# python web-crawler Guessed at parser warning

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to make a web crawler using python (3.8) I mostly think I'm done but I'm getting this error can any body help me and thank's in advance.

Python code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def aliexpress_spider (max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/af/ps4.html?trafficChannel=af&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=ps4&ltype=affiliate&SortType=default&page=" + str(page)
        sourcecode = requests.get(url)
        plaintext = sourcecode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
        for link in soup.findAll('a' , {'class' : 'item-title'}):
            href = "https://www.aliexpress.com" + link.get("href")
            title  = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)
        page += 1


aliexpress_spider(1)
```

Error massege :

```
  GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 11 of the file C:/Users/moham/PycharmProjects/moh/test.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext)
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily a problem. You just havn't provied a praser to use on line 11. You could instead write `soup = BeautifulSoup(plaintext, 'html.parser)` and the warning will disappear

Answer (score -1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def aliexpress_spider (max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/af/ps4.html?trafficChannel=af&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=ps4&ltype=affiliate&SortType=default&page=" + str(page)
        sourcecode = requests.get(url)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode.text ,"html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a' , {'class' : 'item-title'}):
            href = "https://www.aliexpress.com" + link.get("href")
            title  = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)
        print(soup.title)
        page += 1



aliexpress_spider(1)
```